# How do I get NOAA JSON data into PHP?

Tags: php, json, noaa

When I go to http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.4247341&lon=-86.9624086&FcstType=json with my browser I see the expected return (and I like it).

When in PHP I write 
$jj = file_get_contents("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.4247341&lon=-86.9624086&FcstType=json");

I get an error message "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden".

Is there a way to get the data from `http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=38.4247341&lon=-86.9624086&FcstType=json` into PHP?
Note: once I have JSON data in PHP, I know how to deal with it.

Thank you. Hubert Halkin

Comment: They might have blocked your server IP or don't allow the file_get_contents USER_AGENT. Try using Curl and modify the USER_AGENT to a valid browser.

Comment: @sander : Thank you. I have tried different server IPs and  several browsers  without success .

Comment: Can you add the curl code which failed?

Comment: @sander: I do not use curl. I have now added ini_set("user_agent","Safari"); at the top of the PHP code and it works!